# How to extract chain-IDs from PDB files?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, protein-database

I have all the PDB files stored on my local hard disk. The files are in *`pdbXXXX.ent.gz`* format.

I have a python program that reads a text file which must be in the following format:

```
pdb_id  chain_id  resolution
```

How can I prepare this plain text file from all those PDB files?

Comment: The first step is to convert the gunzip file (`.gz`) into uncompressed file(s) and then go from there.

Comment: @jfaccioni, the `.gz` files are already taking 36GB. I need to read them as they are.

Comment: Then take a small amount of data to test. Unzip a single file and take a look at what's inside - that's the first step to figure out how to convert it to your desired format.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean with "read them as they are" - you can uncompress the files in-memory, so they don't take disk space, but you'll need 36GB RAM to store them during execution (likely more). You could create a loop that takes a single `.gz` file, extracts the data and saves them, which would use less memory per loop, but that's a different question than the one you posed. At the end of the day, gunzip files need to be uncompressed in order to work with them, be it in disk or in memory.

Comment: @jfaccioni, I have 64GB RAM.

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about fitting the data in the memory during execution, but you still need to figure out what kind of data you're working with. You can't expect us to guess what kind of file(s) are inside the gunzip compressed files without access to your computer. And without knowing the contents, we can't help transforming it to your desired format.

Comment: @jfaccioni,  *but you still need to figure out what kind of data you're working with. You can't expect us to guess what kind of file(s) are inside the gunzip compressed files without access to your computer.* --- you are joking, right? I already said, they are all individual PDB files in `.gz` format. I downloaded them as they are from the RSCB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse a PDB file with Biopython even when it is compressed. You just need to be careful to open the file in text mode ("rt") - otherwise you end up with a TypeError.

I tested the following script with a rather small sample: 4 zipped PDB entries in a local folder.

```py
import gzip
import warnings
from pathlib import Path
from Bio.PDB.PDBExceptions import PDBConstructionWarning
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

# To get rid of those annoying warnings like 'WARNING: Chain B is discontinuous at line 4059.'
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', PDBConstructionWarning)

parser = PDBParser()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdb_zips = Path("zipped_pdbs").glob('**/*.ent.gz')
    for pdb_filename in pdb_zips:
        with gzip.open(pdb_filename, "rt") as file_handle:
            structure = parser.get_structure("?", file_handle)
        # you could of course parse the pdb code from the file name as well. 
        # But I found this to be easier implemented.       
        pdb_code = structure.header.get("idcode")
        resolution = structure.header.get("resolution")

        for chain in structure.get_chains():
            print(f"{pdb_code}  {chain.id}  {resolution}")
```

The output reads

```
7LWV  A  3.12
7LWV  B  3.12
7LWV  C  3.12
6U9D  A  3.19
6U9D  B  3.19
6U9D  C  3.19
6U9D  D  3.19
6U9D  E  3.19
6U9D  F  3.19
6U9D  G  3.19
6U9D  H  3.19
6U9D  I  3.19
6U9D  J  3.19
6U9D  K  3.19
6U9D  L  3.19
6U9D  M  3.19
6U9D  N  3.19
6U9D  O  3.19
6U9D  P  3.19
6U9D  Q  3.19
6U9D  R  3.19
6U9D  S  3.19
6U9D  T  3.19
6U9D  U  3.19
6U9D  V  3.19
6U9D  W  3.19
6U9D  X  3.19
1F34  A  2.45
1F34  B  2.45
2OXP  A  2.0
```